# Python/regex - Bypass table of contents when extracting text

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of the following:

| identifier | text |
| --- | --- |
| 34678 | 0000950123-04-010521.txt : 20040901..... |
| 87902 | 0000950123-04-010521.txt : 20040901..... |

I am trying extract a portion of text from the "text" variable in Python that follows a line starting with "Item 5.02". I am placing the extracted text in a new variable called ("important_text"). With the help of fellow stack overflowers, I was able to construct the following code to extract the text:

```
    pattern = r'\bItem\s+5\.02\s*([\w\W]*?)(?=\s*(?:Item\s+ 
   [89]\.01|Item\s+5\.03|Item\s+5\.07|Item\s+7\.01|SIGNATURES|SIGNATURE|' + r'Pursuant 
    to the requirements of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934)\b)'.replace(' ', '\s*')

    pd_00['important_text'] = pd_00['text'].str.extract(pattern, re.IGNORECASE, expand=False)
```

So, this is extracting all text between the first occurrence of "Item 5.02" and the first occurrence of various terms (i.e., "Item 8.01", "Item 9.01", "SIGNATURES", etc.).

In general, this does a really good job of extracting the portion of text I am looking for. However, in some instances, the text variable contains a Table of Contents that will have a line starting with "Item 5.02". In these instances, the regex code does not grab the portion of text I need. Does anyone have any advice for how to bypass the Table of Contents?

Here is an example that includes a Table of Contents (apologies for the large amount of text...I thought it would be best to give a full example):

```
    <SEC-DOCUMENT>0000950137-05-007782.txt : 20050623
    <SEC-HEADER>0000950137-05-007782.hdr.sgml : 20050623
    <ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20050623154401
    ACCESSION NUMBER:       0000950137-05-007782
    CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  8-K/A
    PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      3
    CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20050511
    ITEM INFORMATION:       Entry into a Material Definitive Agreement
    ITEM INFORMATION:       Departure of Directors or Principal Officers; Election of 
    Directors; Appointment of Principal Officers
    ITEM INFORMATION:       Financial Statements and Exhibits
    FILED AS OF DATE:       20050623
    DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20050623

    FILER:

COMPANY DATA:   
    COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:         HILLENBRAND INDUSTRIES INC
    CENTRAL INDEX KEY:          0000047518
    STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION: MISCELLANEOUS FURNITURE & FIXTURES [2590]
    IRS NUMBER:             351160484
    STATE OF INCORPORATION:         IN
    FISCAL YEAR END:            0930

FILING VALUES:
    FORM TYPE:      8-K/A
    SEC ACT:        1934 Act
    SEC FILE NUMBER:    001-06651
    FILM NUMBER:        05912533

BUSINESS ADDRESS:   
    STREET 1:       700 STATE ROUTE 46 E
    CITY:           BATESVILLE
    STATE:          IN
    ZIP:            47006-8835
    BUSINESS PHONE:     8129347000
    </SEC-HEADER>
    <DOCUMENT>
    <TYPE>8-K/A
    <SEQUENCE>1
    <FILENAME>c96192ae8vkza.htm
    <DESCRIPTION>AMENDMENT TO CURRENT REPORT
    <TEXT>
    e8vkza

    Table of Contents

    UNITED STATES
    SECURITIES AND EXCHANGE COMMISSION
    Washington, D.C. 20549

    FORM 8-K/A
    CURRENT REPORT
    Pursuant to Section 13 or 15(d) of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934
    Date of Report (Date of earliest event reported): May 11, 2005
    HILLENBRAND INDUSTRIES, INC.
    (Exact name of registrant as specified in its charter)

    Indiana (State or other jurisdiction of incorporation) 1-6651 (Commission File Number) 35-1160484 (IRS Employer Identification No.)

    700 State Route 46 East Batesville, Indiana (Address of principal executive offices) 47006-8835 (Zip Code)

    Registrants telephone number, including area code: (812) 934-7000
    Not Applicable
    (Former name or former address, if changed since last report.)

    Check the appropriate box below if the Form 8-K filing is intended to simultaneously satisfy
    the filing obligation of the registrant under any of the following provisions:

    o Written communications pursuant to Rule 425 under the Securities Act (17 CFR 230.425)

    o Soliciting material pursuant to Rule 14a-12 under the Exchange Act (17 CFR 240.14a-12)

    o Pre-commencement communications pursuant to Rule 14d-2(b) under the Exchange Act
    (17 CFR 240.14d-2(b))

     o Pre-commencement communications pursuant to Rule 13e-4(c) under the Exchange 
    Act
     (17 CFR 240.13e-4(c))

     1

    TABLE OF CONTENTS

    Item 1.01 ENTRY INTO A MATERIAL DEFINITIVE AGREEMENT
    Item 5.02. DEPARTURE OF DIRECTORS OR PRINCIPAL OFFICERS; ELECTION OF DIRECTORS; 
    APPOINTMENT OF PRINCIPAL OFFICERS
    Item 9.01. FINANCIAL STATEMENTS AND EXHIBITS
    SIGNATURES
    EXHIBIT INDEX
    Employment Agreement
    Stock Award

    Table of Contents

    Item 1.01 ENTRY INTO A MATERIAL DEFINITIVE AGREEMENT.

    Item 5.02. DEPARTURE OF DIRECTORS OR PRINCIPAL OFFICERS; ELECTION OF DIRECTORS;
    APPOINTMENT OF PRINCIPAL OFFICERS.
    As previously disclosed, on May 11, 2005 Hillenbrand Industries, Inc.s Board of 
    Directors
    appointed Rolf A. Classon to serve as President and Chief Executive Officer of 
    Hillenbrand on an
    interim basis. At the time the Form 8-K announcing this appointment was filed, 
    Mr. Classon did not
    have an employment agreement with Hillenbrand.
```

Similar to the above example, The Table of Contents will usually start with "Table of Contents" and end with "Table of Contents". To further complicate things, the text will sometimes randomly say "Table of Contents" towards the beginning of the text (this is also shown in the above example).

Here is what I would like to extract:

```
    DEPARTURE OF DIRECTORS OR PRINCIPAL OFFICERS; ELECTION OF DIRECTORS;
    APPOINTMENT OF PRINCIPAL OFFICERS.
    As previously disclosed, on May 11, 2005 Hillenbrand Industries, Inc.s Board of 
    Directors
    appointed Rolf A. Classon to serve as President and Chief Executive Officer of 
    Hillenbrand on an
    interim basis. At the time the Form 8-K announcing this appointment was filed, 
    Mr. Classon did not
    have an employment agreement with Hillenbrand.
```

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to skip regex and work with list of lines - first search line with `Item 5.02.` and later get line by line until you get line with ending element(s).

Comment: Is the TOC at the end of the text? Then just add `(?si:TABLE\s+OF\s+CONTENTS.*)|` at the start of your pattern.